# How to use asset_pack_path with background-image inline css

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

Hey guys I'm having a problem getting this to work.

I have these 2 lines the top one works the second one doesnt for some reason.

this one works:

```
%img.img-fluid{:alt => "...", :src => "#{asset_pack_path('media/img/covers/cover-2.jpg')}"}/
```

This one doesnt work:

```
.w-100.h-100.bg-cover{:style => "background-image: url(#{asset_pack_path('media/img/covers/cover-2.jpg')});"}
```

I have added the right lines to the application.js file

```
const images = require.context('../img', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

But it doesnt work. Not sure why the first one works and loads the images fine but the second one doesnt load at all. Its the same file so makes no sense to me. Im using haml.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: "Does'nt work" is pretty useless information. Start by comparing the html output and looking if its a haml issue, a CSS issue or a assets pipeline issue (which I doubt).

Comment: I found that line of code from another person who asked the same question and it seems to work for them. The asset pipeline isnt used in this case its using webpacker to serve up the images. I put the asset_pack_path('media/img/covers/cover-2.jpg') into a binding pry to see what is being served and it was the correct file but for some reason it just wasnt loading. Even tho the other lines worked. I ended up just going back to the asset pipeline I spent too much time trying to figure out what was wrong.